# Hide first cell of a group in Tablix - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I want to hide the first cell of the group , please provide me the solution for this and i am using the previous function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dH8p.png)

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update you question with things like...
What have you tried so far? What does your current expression look like?

Comment: Show what your data set looks like.. i.e. the sample data you use for arriving at this report

Comment: I am writing a expression like =Total Value - Previous(Total Value), by doing this the first value is showing the default because it is not substracting

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a row number column in data set and use that in expression with if clause